# Save checkboxes states through fragments in Android

Tags: android, checkbox, android-fragments

I'm currently working on an app with a two lists (in different fragments) with checkboxes.

A few screenshots to show you the display :

[Talks Screens](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6oTxi.png)

[Papers Screens](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2T8MG.png)

Now I would like to be able to

1) save all the checkboxes states with the «save» button (and load them with the «load» button)

2) "link" the checkboxes so that if I click on one in the Talks screens it gets clicked too in the Papers Screens.

I know I could save these by using SharedPreferences, but they are build with an adapter and so all I have is, for instance

```
    @Override
public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {

    // We only create the view if its needed
    if (view == null) {
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.child_row, null);

        // Set the click listener for the checkbox
        view.findViewById(R.id.check1).setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    Paper p = (Paper) getItem(position);

    // Set the example text and the state of the checkbox
    CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.check1);
    //cb.setChecked(p.isSelected());
    // We tag the data object to retrieve it on the click listener.

    TextView paper = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.papername);
    if (paper != null)
        paper.setText(p.getTitle());

    TextView author = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.authorname);
    if( author!= null )
        author.setText( p.getAuthor() );

    return view;
}
```

So no identificator for each checkbox. Is this an issue I can handle simply?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

you can use this

```
SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("syllabus", 0);
Boolean isChecked = settings.getBoolean("cbx1_ischecked", false);
checkbox1.setChecked(isChecked );
```

Comment: Thanks for your help!

Where can I use this? In my adapter? Or the fragment?

Comment: Use this in your adapter because you can only get status of checkbox inside your adapter.

Comment: Get data from shared prefs in activity or fragment and then set to adapter 
Don't get it in adapter!

Answer (score 0):

at beginning   in the page [Fragment tutorial](http://www.intertech.com/Blog/saving-and-retrieving-android-instance-state-part-2/)  U can obtain important concept.

also u can refer to any UI component with getActivity().findviewbyId(...) or getView().findviewbyId(...)
hop to useful