# android fragment to fragment communication : update recyclerView of the ReceiverFragment via interface

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

I have two fragments and I am trying to update the recyclerView of the ReceiverFragment via interface. Both fragments have its own adapter (SenderAdapter and ReceiverAdapter).

I have to mention that I also have two SQLDatabase, where group.db is used to populate the SenderFragment and client.db is used to populate the ReceiverFragment.

But ReceiverFragment will only be populate if a CheckBox is ticked in the SenderAdapter.

All the communication between the fragments is ok. When I tick a CheckBox, The SenderAdapter sends a message to MainActivity and the MainActivity sends the same message to ReceiverFragment.

This is SenderFragment:

[image: This is the SenderFragment:]

This would be the desired result.

[image: desired result]

When I use the message from interface to read the client.db, I get the nullException.

This is the ReceiverFragment:

```
public class ReceiverFragment extends Fragment {

    View view;
    private RecyclerView mClientList;
    private RecyclerView.Adapter mClientListAdapter;
    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager mClientListLayoutManager;

    private String receivedFromSender;

    ArrayList<ClientObject> clientList;

    SQLiteDatabase clientListTable;
    ClientRepository clientRepository;


    private static String rootPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/PassKeyBF/";


    public ReceiverFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    public String getMessageFromSender(String message){
        if (message != null) {
            receivedFromSender = message;
            Log.i("debinf recfrag", "message from sender (function) is : " + receivedFromSender);

            //Log.i("debinf recgfrag", "mContext in interface : " + mContext);

            if (message != null) {
                if (new File(rootPath + receivedFromSender, "client.db").isFile()) {
                    clientReading(message);
                }
            }                                  


        }

        return null;

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_receiver, container, false);

        // If I use mContext instead of getContext(), I get rid of the context error showed below.
        //mContext = getContext();

        clientList = new ArrayList<>();

        initializeRecyclerView();
        //clientReading("-LWBPaM7RA9UOcUVty79");

        return view;
    }

    private void clientReading(String pathToClientTable) {

        if (new File(rootPath + pathToClientTable, "client.db").isFile()) {

            Log.i("debinf recgfrag", "mContext in clientReading" + mContext);

            ClientDatabaseHelper clientDatabaseHelper = new ClientDatabaseHelper(mContext,"client.db", rootPath+pathToClientTable+"/");

            clientListTable = clientDatabaseHelper.getReadableDatabase();
            clientRepository = new ClientRepository(clientListTable);

            clientList = clientRepository.SearchAllClients();
            Log.i("debinf recfrag", "clientList in clientReading is " + clientList.get(0).getName());
            mClientListAdapter = new ReceiverAdapter(mContext,clientList);
            mClientList.setAdapter(mClientListAdapter);
            //mClientListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        }

    }

    private void initializeRecyclerView() {

        mClientList = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.clientList);
        mClientList.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
        mClientList.setHasFixedSize(false);
        mClientListLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(mContext,LinearLayout.VERTICAL,false);
        mClientList.setLayoutManager(mClientListLayoutManager);

        mClientListAdapter = new ReceiverAdapter(mContext,clientList);
        mClientList.setAdapter(mClientListAdapter);

    }

}
```

This is the ReceiverAdapter

```
public class ReceiverAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ReceiverAdapter.ReceiverViewHolder> {

    ArrayList<ClientObject> clientList;
    Context mContext;

    private ReceiverAdapter adapter;

    public ReceiverAdapter(Context mContext, ArrayList<ClientObject> clientList) {
        this.clientList = clientList;
        this.mContext = mContext;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ReceiverViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View layoutView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_callcenter_client, null, false);

        RecyclerView.LayoutParams lp = new RecyclerView.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        layoutView.setLayoutParams(lp);

        ReceiverViewHolder rcv = new ReceiverViewHolder(layoutView);
        return rcv;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ReceiverViewHolder holder, int position) {

        holder.mName.setText(clientList.get(position).getName());
        holder.mPhone.setText(clientList.get(position).getPhone());

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return clientList.size();
    }

    public class ReceiverViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        public TextView mName, mPhone;
        //public LinearLayout mLayout;

        public ReceiverViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            mName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.client_name);
            mPhone = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.client_phone);
            //mLayout = (LinearLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.layoutItemClient);
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

I changed the ReceiverFragment so that it could be more understandable.

That's the FATAL ERROR I get when I use the getContext(). I simply cannot make a connection with my SQLDatabase.

```
2019-01-31 15:41:45.118 22318-22318/com.example.aliton.passkeybetweenfrags E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.aliton.passkeybetweenfrags, PID: 22318
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.io.File android.content.Context.getDatabasePath(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:352)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getReadableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:322)
        at com.example.aliton.passkeybetweenfrags.ReceiverFragment.clientReading(ReceiverFragment.java:104)
        at com.example.aliton.passkeybetweenfrags.ReceiverFragment.getMessageFromSender(ReceiverFragment.java:53)
        at com.example.aliton.passkeybetweenfrags.MainActivity.getMessage(MainActivity.java:64)
        at com.example.aliton.passkeybetweenfrags.SenderAdapter$1.onCheckedChanged(SenderAdapter.java:54)
        at android.widget.CompoundButton.setChecked(CompoundButton.java:171)
        at android.widget.CompoundButton.toggle(CompoundButton.java:127)
        at android.widget.CompoundButton.performClick(CompoundButton.java:132)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:6574)
        at android.view.View.access$3100(View.java:778)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:25885)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

Now, when I suppress getContext() and make it static in mContext. I can make a connection with SQLDatabase, but I get this FATAL error because the ReceiverAdapter:

```
2019-01-31 15:35:05.541 21936-21936/com.example.aliton.passkeybetweenfrags E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.aliton.passkeybetweenfrags, PID: 21936
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.setAdapter(android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter)' on a null object reference
        at com.example.aliton.passkeybetweenfrags.ReceiverFragment.clientReading(ReceiverFragment.java:110)
        at com.example.aliton.passkeybetweenfrags.ReceiverFragment.getMessageFromSender(ReceiverFragment.java:53)
        at com.example.aliton.passkeybetweenfrags.MainActivity.getMessage(MainActivity.java:64)
        at com.example.aliton.passkeybetweenfrags.SenderAdapter$1.onCheckedChanged(SenderAdapter.java:54)
        at android.widget.CompoundButton.setChecked(CompoundButton.java:171)
        at android.widget.CompoundButton.toggle(CompoundButton.java:127)
        at android.widget.CompoundButton.performClick(CompoundButton.java:132)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:6574)
        at android.view.View.access$3100(View.java:778)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:25885)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

I can either get an error while reading the SQLDatabase (client.db) or while updating the ReceiverAdapter.

This is the link for the Main folder of the app:

https://1drv.ms/u/s!AjteqjTsJm9qgn6kODT9OJmMcY4e

This is the link to the SQLDatabase (group.db and client.db)

https://1drv.ms/u/s!AjteqjTsJm9qgn_L52cz3lDWOOWe

Comment: you could paste the error log or tell where exactly does it throw the error :)

Comment: Please rename your `mClientList` as `recyclerView` so it's easier to understand… lol. Anyway ReceiverFragment  calls `initializeRecyclerView();` which sets the adapter on the recyclerView with the contents of `clientList` (which is an empty arraylist); no need to do that, if you will then call `clientReading("-LWBPaM7RA9UOcUVty79");` which fetches from your repository and sets the adapter again. Initialize the RV when you have data. Please post where you're getting the error (log) it's unclear WHO is calling WHO and it what order because you skipped that.

Comment: **clientReading("-LWBPaM7RA9UOcUVty79");** is just a test to make sure that everything is working fine and it is just like in the picture. But when I use the interface I get an error while connecting to SQLDatabase because of getContext(). So when I make getContext() static in mContext, I read the SQLDatabase, but I get an error in the ReceiverAdapter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found an answer.

The whole problem happened in the MainActivity. I was communicating from the MainActivity to the ReceiverFragment like this :

```
ReceiverFragment receiverFragment = new ReceiverFragment();
```

And sending the message like this:

```
   @Override
    public void getMessage(String message) {

        receiverFragment.getMessageFromSender(message);

    }
```

The message was been passed from MainActivity to ReceiverFragment normally, But I was getting a NullPointerException for the recyclerView of the ReceiverFragment.

The problem was solved by using the following way to deliver the message to the ReceiverFragment (answer found in this link https://www.journaldev.com/14207/android-passing-data-between-fragments):

```
@Override
    public void getMessage(String message) {

        String tag = "android:switcher:" + R.id.tabs_pager + ":" + 1;
        ReceiverFragment rf = (ReceiverFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(tag);
        rf.getMessageFromSender(message);

    }
```

The links for the code and the SQLDatabase (group.db and client.db) are still available for download.

For those who are starting in Android like me and interested in the code, please do not forget to change the delivering function in the MainActivity.

Thank you all and good luck!