# Firestore not updating after screen is turned off

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am running my app on my physical device and the real time Firestore update works fine till the screen is turned off.

Here is the function I use to update my data:

```
private void updateNotifyGroup(String groupCreator, final String groupKey) {

    // IT WORKS EXACTLY AS IN addChildEventListener()
    // ADD groupRepository.getCreatorGroup(groupKeyMsg) instead of currentUser
    Log.i("debinf callfrag", "groupCreator" + groupCreator);
    Log.i("debinf callfrag", "groupKey" + groupKey);
    CollectionReference collectionReference = CallRoot.collection(groupCreator).document(groupKey).collection("ClientList");

    collectionReference.addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onEvent(@javax.annotation.Nullable QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots, @javax.annotation.Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException e) {

            if (e != null) {
                Log.i("debinf callfrag", "Listen failed.", e);
                return;
            }

            if (queryDocumentSnapshots != null && !queryDocumentSnapshots.isEmpty()){

                for (DocumentChange documentChange : queryDocumentSnapshots.getDocumentChanges()) {
                    //Log.i("debinf callfrag", "entering in loop = " + documentChange.getDocument().getData());
                    switch (documentChange.getType()) {
                        case ADDED:
                            Log.i("debinf callfrag", "data added = " + documentChange.getDocument().getData().get("notifyGroup"));

                            for (int i = 0; i < clientList.size(); i++) {

                                if (clientList.get(i).getCid().equals(documentChange.getDocument().getId())) {
                                    //Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Client name is " + clientList.get(i).getName(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    clientList.get(i).setNotifygroup(documentChange.getDocument().getData().get("notifyGroup").toString());
                                    mClientListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                                    break;

                                }
                            }
                            break;

                        case MODIFIED:
                            Log.i("debinf callfrag", "data modified = " + documentChange.getDocument().getId());
                            for (int i = 0; i < clientList.size(); i++) {

                                if (clientList.get(i).getCid().equals(documentChange.getDocument().getId())) {
                                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Client name is " + clientList.get(i).getName(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    clientList.get(i).setNotifygroup(documentChange.getDocument().getData().get("notifyGroup").toString());
                                    mClientListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                                    break;

                                }
                            }
                            break;

                        case REMOVED:
                            Log.i("debinf callfrag", "data removed = " + documentChange.getDocument().getData());
                            break;
                    }
                }

            }

        }
    });

}
```

That is the result before the screen is turned off:

```
02-10 16:42:32.890 20019-20019/com.example.aliton.myapp I/debinf callfrag: groupCreatorAJ0uyrTm95ODvCuua71cB17ueBt2
02-10 16:42:32.890 20019-20019/com.example.aliton.myapp I/debinf callfrag: groupKey-LXM0N48OOHTpwa8kNmJ
02-10 16:42:32.981 20019-20019/com.example.aliton.myapp I/debinf callfrag: data added = Desligado
02-10 16:42:32.982 20019-20019/com.example.aliton.myapp I/debinf callfrag: data added = Agendado
02-10 16:42:32.983 20019-20019/com.example.aliton.myapp I/debinf callfrag: data added = Ligar
02-10 16:42:32.984 20019-20019/com.example.aliton.myapp I/debinf callfrag: data added = Nao Atende
02-10 16:42:32.985 20019-20019/com.example.aliton.myapp I/debinf callfrag: data added = Andamento
02-10 16:42:32.987 20019-20019/com.example.aliton.myapp I/debinf callfrag: data added = Finalizado
02-10 16:42:32.988 20019-20019/com.example.aliton.myapp I/debinf callfrag: data added = Recusado
```

When my device turns the screen off , the lifecycle is `onPause` and `onStop`. When turning the screen on, the lifecycle is `onStart` and `onResume`.

My app works similarly to the app presented in this link:

[android fragment to fragment communication : update recyclerView of the ReceiverFragment via interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54464482/android-fragment-to-fragment-communication-update-recyclerview-of-the-receiver?noredirect=1#comment95738198_54464482)

After I turn the screen on, I manually change the value of the field from **Ligar** to **AnyThing** and my physical device does not get notified about the change in Firestore.

Just my Emulator gets notified about the change in Firestore.

My physical device only gets notified after re-running on Android Studio:

```
02-10 17:25:33.296 21287-21287/com.example.aliton.myapp I/debinf callfrag: groupCreatorAJ0uyrTm95ODvCuua71cB17ueBt2
02-10 17:25:33.296 21287-21287/com.example.aliton.myapp I/debinf callfrag: groupKey-LXM0N48OOHTpwa8kNmJ
02-10 17:25:33.903 21287-21287/com.example.aliton.myapp I/debinf callfrag: data added = Desligado
02-10 17:25:33.904 21287-21287/com.example.aliton.myapp I/debinf callfrag: data added = Agendado
02-10 17:25:33.905 21287-21287/com.example.aliton.myapp I/debinf callfrag: data added = AnyThing
02-10 17:25:33.906 21287-21287/com.example.aliton.myapp I/debinf callfrag: data added = Nao Atende
02-10 17:25:33.907 21287-21287/com.example.aliton.myapp I/debinf callfrag: data added = Andamento
02-10 17:25:33.908 21287-21287/com.example.aliton.myapp I/debinf callfrag: data added = Finalizado
02-10 17:25:33.909 21287-21287/com.example.aliton.myapp I/debinf callfrag: data added = Recusado
02-10 17:25:34.945 21287-21287/com.example.aliton.myapp I/debinf callfrag: data modified = 629584107
```

How do I make permanent connection to Firestore even atfer the screen is turned on again?

Answer (score 0):

Android will stop your app from functioning when the user isn't actively using it.  This is to prevent apps from draining the battery.  You should allow for this to happen - read about [doze and app standby modes](https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby) in the Android documentation.

If you really must continue doing work when the screen is off, you need to create a [foreground service](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services#Foreground).  Note that the documentation warns you about limiting use of foreground services.  If you are just trying to maintain a connection to Firestore, that is not a very good use of a foreground service.

Comment: keep the app running when the screen is turned off is not recommended and I can understand it. I just do not understand why my app looses connection with Firestore after screen is turned off and just gets notified again when I re-run it on Android Studio while my Emulator always gets notified.

Comment: Read the doze mode docs I linked: " The following restrictions apply to your apps while in Doze:

    Network access is suspended. "

Comment: Also, the SDK may choose to drop the connection when it's not being used, in order to save the user's bandwidth.

Comment: doze mode docs you linked says: _As soon as the user wakes the device by moving it, turning on the screen, or connecting a charger, the system exits Doze and all apps return to normal activity_. This should include reestablishing the connection with the Firestore, right?

Comment: Only if you need to perform a query.

Comment: How could I get past this problem. Could you help me by showing some code to reestablish connection with Firestore after the screen is on again?

Answer (score 0):

This is not a solution, but it made me think that it solved the problem.

I do not know if the solution that I am presenting here is the appropriated solution, but it seems to solve the problem of reestablishing the connection with Firestore after turning on the screen (returning from **Doze Mode**).

I implemented a connection with Firestore in `onStart`:

```
@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    Log.i("debinf callfrag", "onStart");
    if (groupKeyFromSender != null) {
        updateNotifyGroup(groupCreatorFromSender, groupKeyFromSender);
    }

}
```

For those who are starting in Android Studio like me and are interested in the code to understand new functionalities, here comes the code:

```
public class CallFragment extends Fragment {

    View view;
    private RecyclerView mClientList;
    private RecyclerView.Adapter mClientListAdapter;
    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager mClientListLayoutManager;

    private String receivedFromSender;
    private String currentUser, groupKeyFromSender, groupCreatorFromSender;

    ArrayList<ClientObject> clientList;

    SQLiteDatabase clientListTable;
    ClientRepository clientRepository;

    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    FirebaseFirestore CallRoot;

    static Context mContext;

    private static String rootPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/";


    public CallFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    public void getDataFromGroupFragment(String groupCreatorFromSender, String groupKeyFromSender, boolean addToCall) {
        if (groupKeyFromSender != null) {
            this.groupCreatorFromSender = groupCreatorFromSender;
            this.groupKeyFromSender = groupKeyFromSender;
            if (new File(rootPath + groupKeyFromSender, "client.db").isFile()) {
                if (addToCall) {
                    addClientToCall(groupCreatorFromSender, groupKeyFromSender);
                } else if (!addToCall) {
                    removeClientOfCall(groupKeyFromSender);
                }
            }
        }
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.call_fragment, container, false);

        setHasOptionsMenu(true);

        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        currentUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
        CallRoot = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();

        mContext = container.getContext();
        //Log.i("debinf recgfrag", "mContext in onCreate : " + getContext());

        clientList = new ArrayList<>();

        initializeRecyclerView();

        return view;
    }


    private void removeClientOfCall(String pathToClientTable) {

        //Log.i("debinf recgfrag", "mContext in clientReading" + mContext);

        ClientDatabaseHelper clientDatabaseHelper = new ClientDatabaseHelper(mContext,"client.db", rootPath+pathToClientTable+"/");

        clientListTable = clientDatabaseHelper.getReadableDatabase();
        clientRepository = new ClientRepository(clientListTable);
        ArrayList<ClientObject> clientObjects = clientRepository.SearchAllClients();

        clientList.removeAll(clientObjects);
        Log.i("debinf recfrag", "clientList.size() Remove in clientReading is " + clientList.size());
        mClientListAdapter = new CallAdapter(mContext,clientList);
        //Log.i("debinf recfrag", "mClientList in clientReading is " + mClientList);
        mClientList.setAdapter(mClientListAdapter);
        mClientListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    }

    private void addClientToCall(String groupCreator, String groupKey) {

        ClientDatabaseHelper clientDatabaseHelper = new ClientDatabaseHelper(mContext,"client.db", rootPath+groupKey+"/");

        clientListTable = clientDatabaseHelper.getReadableDatabase();
        clientRepository = new ClientRepository(clientListTable);
        ArrayList<ClientObject> clientObjects = clientRepository.SearchAllClients();

        clientList.addAll(clientObjects);
        Log.i("debinf recfrag", "clientList in clientReading is " + clientList.get(0).getName());

        updateNotifyGroup(groupCreator, groupKey);

        mClientListAdapter = new CallAdapter(mContext,clientList);
        //Log.i("debinf recfrag", "mClientList in clientReading is " + mClientList);
        mClientList.setAdapter(mClientListAdapter);
        //mClientListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    }

    private void updateNotifyGroup(String groupCreator, final String groupKey) {

        // IT WORKS EXACTLY AS IN addChildEventListener()
        // ADD groupRepository.getCreatorGroup(groupKeyMsg) instead of currentUser
        Log.i("debinf callfrag", "groupCreator" + groupCreator);
        Log.i("debinf callfrag", "groupKey" + groupKey);
        CollectionReference collectionReference = CallRoot.collection(groupCreator).document(groupKey).collection("ClientList");

        collectionReference.addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onEvent(@javax.annotation.Nullable QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots, @javax.annotation.Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException e) {

                if (e != null) {
                    Log.i("debinf callfrag", "Listen failed.", e);
                    return;
                }

                if (queryDocumentSnapshots != null && !queryDocumentSnapshots.isEmpty()){

                    for (DocumentChange documentChange : queryDocumentSnapshots.getDocumentChanges()) {
                        //Log.i("debinf callfrag", "entering in loop = " + documentChange.getDocument().getData());
                        switch (documentChange.getType()) {
                            case ADDED:
                                Log.i("debinf callfrag", "data added = " + documentChange.getDocument().getData().get("notifyGroup"));

                                for (int i = 0; i < clientList.size(); i++) {

                                    if (clientList.get(i).getCid().equals(documentChange.getDocument().getId())) {
                                        //Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Client name is " + clientList.get(i).getName(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                        clientList.get(i).setNotifygroup(documentChange.getDocument().getData().get("notifyGroup").toString());
                                        mClientListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                                        break;

                                    }
                                }
                                break;

                            case MODIFIED:
                                Log.i("debinf callfrag", "data modified = " + documentChange.getDocument().getId());
                                for (int i = 0; i < clientList.size(); i++) {

                                    if (clientList.get(i).getCid().equals(documentChange.getDocument().getId())) {
                                        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Client name is " + clientList.get(i).getName(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                        clientList.get(i).setNotifygroup(documentChange.getDocument().getData().get("notifyGroup").toString());
                                        mClientListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                                        break;

                                    }
                                }
                                break;

                            case REMOVED:
                                Log.i("debinf callfrag", "data removed = " + documentChange.getDocument().getData());
                                break;
                        }
                    }

                }

            }
        });

    }

    private void initializeRecyclerView() {

        mClientList = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.clientList);
        mClientList.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
        mClientList.setHasFixedSize(false);
        mClientListLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(mContext,LinearLayout.VERTICAL,false);
        mClientList.setLayoutManager(mClientListLayoutManager);

        mClientListAdapter = new CallAdapter(mContext,clientList);
        mClientList.setAdapter(mClientListAdapter);

    }


    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        Log.i("debinf callfrag", "onStart");
        if (groupKeyFromSender != null) {
            updateNotifyGroup(groupCreatorFromSender, groupKeyFromSender);
        }

    }


    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        menu.clear();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.options_call, menu);
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

        switch (item.getItemId()){
            case R.id.play_option:
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "PlayOption Selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                doSomething();
                return true;

            case R.id.stop_option:
                Toast.makeText(mContext, "option Stop", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return true;

        }

        return false;

    }

    private void doSomething() {
        Toast.makeText(mContext, "didSomething", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}
```

To make my code a bit clearer, I am updating the button text:

Good luck!